# Помощь в оптимизации участка кода

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация

У меня стоит задача сформировать звуковой сигнал (меандр) из 8-ми гармоник, каждая из которой может иметь или не иметь сдвиг по фазе (на пи).

```py
#data - массив с байтами, в формате ['01010101', '11110000']
ADS = len(data) * SPP #Вычисляю размер массива под сигнал
signal = []
for i in range(ADS):
    signal.append(0)
# Формируем по одному периоду сигнала на каждый байт
for b in range(len(data)):
    d = 0
    for N in range(1, 17, 2):
        for i in range(SPP):
            index = i + (b * SPP)
            signal[index] += harm(N, FREQ, i, SPS, int(data[b][d]))
            #s.next()
        d += 1
```

```py
# Функция для вычисления отдельной гармоники
def harm(N, freq, cs, sps, ph):
    arg = freq*N*2*np.pi*(cs/sps)
    if ph:
        arg += np.pi
    return AMPLITUDE*(4/np.pi)*np.sin(arg)/N
```

Хотел бы узнать, могу ли я как-то оптимизировать данный участок кода. Я думал использовать map, но не придумал, как заменить i (номер текущего отсчёта).
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что такое `SPS`?

Comment: Ещё бы функцию `harm` посмотреть. Ну и так навскидку можно попробовать декорировать `harm` декоратором `functools.lru_cache`. Но тут будет ещё завесить от того, насколько велико значение `SPP`. Если не поможет, тогда копать в сторону `Numba`, либо разбираться в вычислениях и как-то их векторизовать через `Numpy`, но это придётся понять, что вообще делает этот алгоритм.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, SPS - количество отсчётов в секунду. Я использую 48000 и передаю в harm, чтобы вычислить "текущий" момент времени для sin()

Comment: @CrazyElf, добавил @lru_cache(maxsize=SPP), прирост скорости есть, но не весомый (я бы сказал, 5% от общего времени выполнения программы я выиграл). Хотелось бы побольше, т.к. это самый "долгий" участок кода

Comment: В питоне нет оптимизации

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков Этого мало, это только на самый внутренний цикл хватит. Нужно хотя бы `@lru_cache(maxsize=SPP*16*2)`, чтобы ещё и циклы который выше захватились по аргументам. Если сработает, потом ещё попробуйте преобразование последнего аргумента в `int(...)` перенести внутрь функции `harm`, это может ещё немного сэкономить, если кэш будет работать. Преобразование строки в `int` тоже штука затратная.

Comment: @Olegator36 В питоне есть оптимизации. Кроме перечисленных мной выше ещё есть многопоточность (хоть и урезанная) и мультипроцессность.

Comment: Дайте примеры значений для `len(data)` и `SPP`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, SPP - где-то от 30 до 60, а len(data) - несколько сотен тысяч

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, попробую

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков Там ещё хорошо бы `data[b]` вынести в отдельную временную переменную из двух внутренних циклов, но опять же это уже мелкая оптимизация скорее всего будет.

Comment: @CrazyElf, Спосибо большое, теперь примерно на 30% меньше времени занимает выполнение

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков Маловато будет ))  А можете показать что напишет `print(harm.cache_info())` в конце кода если напечатать?

Comment: @CrazyElf, Конечно. CacheInfo(hits=4614144, misses=768, maxsize=1536, currsize=768)

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков А, ну тогда можно если что в 2 раза меньше кэш сделать, я не заметил, что у вас цикл с шагом 2. Хотя это экономия на спичках. А так то кэш хорошо сработал, значит тормозит уже что-то другое. А вот попробуйте начальную инициализацию `signal` сделать так вместо цикла с `append`: `signal = [0] * ADS`. Добавление элементов к списку - это фактически копирование списка, сложность `O(N)`, может здесь вообще это всё тормозит.

Comment: Я посмотрел, инициализация раз в 20 должна ускориться по идее, так что точно её попробуйте. Вместо порядка 2с будет 100мс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробую переписать код, чтобы сделать некоторые оптимизации по итогам обсуждения. Хотя самое лучшее было бы написать "векторную" версию кода на `Numpy`, но это надо думать. Попробую оптимизировать по мелочи, ну и просто чуть попроще код написать. В чём суть изменений:

- кэшируем вызов функции `harm`
- меняем долгую инициализацию списка через `append` на быструю
- выносим получение `data[b]` из внутренних циклов, теперь это `item`
- вычисление `int()` для последнего аргумента функции `harm` наоборот переносим внутрь кэшированной функции
- перебор элементов коллекций и их индексов делаем через enumerate - это просто удобнее

```py
from functools import lru_cache

# Функция для вычисления отдельной гармоники
@lru_cache(maxsize=SPP*16)
def harm(N, freq, cs, sps, ph):
    arg = freq*N*2*np.pi*(cs/sps)
    if int(ph): # <-- перенёс преобразование в int сюда
        arg += np.pi
    return AMPLITUDE*(4/np.pi)*np.sin(arg)/N

#data - массив с байтами, в формате ['01010101', '11110000']
ADS = len(data) * SPP #Вычисляю размер массива под сигнал
signal = [0] * ADS # <-- Такая инициализация списка должна быть сильно быстрее
# Формируем по одному периоду сигнала на каждый байт
for b, item in enumerate(data):
    for d, N in enumerate(range(1, 17, 2)):
        for i in range(SPP):
            index = i + (b * SPP)
            signal[index] += harm(N, FREQ, i, SPS, item[d]) # <-- изменён последний аргумент!
```

Какие ещё можно попробовать сделать дальнейшие оптимизации:

- заменить функции от `Numpy` которые `np.` на функции из `math`, потому что для скаляров скорее всего `Numpy` будет даже медленнее; `Numpy` быстрый только для массивов/векторов/матриц.
- перебор элементов в `item` тоже вынести выше из внутреннего цикла, но это уже мелочи, наверное
- ну и, наконец, вместо `int(ph)` можно сделать словарик, это тоже будет быстрее:

```py
str2int = {
    '0': 0,
    '1': 1
}

if str2int[ph]:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Значение `signal[index]` может быть вычислено как табличная функция:

```
def harm(N, cs, ph):
    arg = FREQ*N*2*np.pi*(cs/SPS)
    if ph:
        arg += np.pi
    return AMPLITUDE*(4/np.pi)*np.sin(arg)/N

@functools.cache
def harm_sum(i, byte): 
    return sum(
        harm(N, i, int(bit))
        for bit, N in zip(byte, range(1, 17, 2))
    )

for j, byte in enumerate(data):
    for i in range(SPP):
        index = i + (j * SPP)
        signal[index] = harm_sum(i, byte)
```

Функция `harm_sum` вызывается для `SPP * 256` вариантов аргументов. Если принять `SPP = 60` то получим таблицу из `15360` значений. Внутренности `harm_sum` не оптимизировались.

Тесты делались для констант

```
SPP = 60
FREQ = 300
SPS = 48000
AMPLITUDE = 2.5
```

Времена работы:

> ```
>                    время работы
> число байт   оригинальный   harm_sum
>                  код
>         10      0.010         0.012
>        100      0.152         0.098
>      1 000      0.930         0.263
>     10 000      9.283         0.401
>    100 000     95.210         1.691
>  1 000 000      -            15.252
> 10 000 000      -           141.268
> ```

Если требуется ускорить код ещё, следует отказаться от байтов в виде строк, значения `harm_sum` сохранить в прямоугольной таблице `SPP*256` адресуемой значением байта.

**P.S.** Странно что функция выродилась в таблицу. Возможно я сделал ошибку, хотя тесты показывают что старый и новый код считают одинаково.